# Laravel Performance issue in Production server

Tags: laravel-5

Hi i just put my app in production and the laravel application is very slow, even slow then in my local server.

May i know any trips and tricks to increase peformance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run this in command line to boost the performance

```
   composer dump-autoload
php artisan clear-compiled
php artisan config:cache
php artisan route:cache
php artisan optimize --force
```